# Varistor transient overvoltage protection of generator

Tags: power, power-electronics, generator, alternator

Using a varistor is a common practice in alternator excitation system. It is used with rotating rectifier diode. Is it used for transient overvoltage protection? 
[image]

Is it protecting diode or rotor winding. How this overvoltage may occur?

Comment: So, could you please remove the other question now...

Answer (score 1):

The over-voltage condition is from the counter-emf that is caused by the field collapsing when the generator stops.

Comment: Thanks. Would you explain counter emf?

Comment: I'm not going to go totally in depth, but its the voltage induced in a coil when its field collapses. I see they refer to it as back emf via search engines, but it is not a really the correct word for it, and counter emf has been the established industry terminology for decades. And when I went to school for this 30 years ago, it was called counter EMF. The terminology "back EMF" should be removed from academia because no one I know in the field uses that term. here is a page about counter emf: http://www.industrial-electronics.com/AC-DC-motors/44_Counter-EMF.html

Comment: So the varistor is protecting rotating diode or rotor winding?

Comment: the dioides, because of the transient reverse bias voltage that gets induced from the magnetic field collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

The varistor will protect anything that would otherwise be damaged above the varistor voltage.